# Generating lists in a while loop and populating them with dynamically generated variables (Python)

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dynamic, exec

Good day!
I am creating a program for solving SLAE using matrices. The matrix looks like this:

```
a11 + a12 + ... + a1n = b1
a21 + a22 + ... + a2n = b2
.........................
an1 + an2 + ... + ann = bn
```

The order of the matrix and the number of variables are not known in advance, so you need to generate them automatically using the `exec` function:

```
rows = float(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
columns = float(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
row_index = 1
i = 1

while i <= columns:
    exec("a_{}{} = {}".format(row_index, i, float(input("Enter the value of the index a{}{} : ".format(row_index, i)))))
    i += 1

    if i == columns + 1:
        row_index += 1
        i = 1
    if row_index == rows + 1:
        break

while row_index <= rows + 1:
    exec("row_{} = []".format(row_index))
    row_index += 1
```

For further calculations with matrix rows, it is necessary to add their elements to the generated list of the form

```
row_1 = [a11, a12, ...an]
```

or a dictionary of the form

```
matrix = {row_1 = {a11 : 1, a12 : 2, a13 : 3},
          row_2 = {a21 : 4, a22 : 5, a23 : 6},
          ...................................}
```

How can this be achieved? The `append()` method does not work.

**Are there methods in python to dynamically create lists/dictionaries and populate them with data?**

Any information on the topic would be helpful!

Comment: " so you need to generate them automatically using the exec function" - No, no, no. Use lists. Don't try to give names to individual items of the list first.

Comment: "The append() method does not work" - yes, it does. Please show the exact code that you tried and how exactly it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly try using dictionary for this.
Try this piece of code :

```
rows = int(input("Enter the number of rows: "))
columns = int(input("Enter the number of columns: "))
row_index = 1
i = 1
dict_matrix={}
while row_index <= rows :
    i=1
    row_name="row_"+str(row_index)
    dict_matrix[row_name]={}
    while i <= columns:
        col_name="a"+str(row_index)+str(i)
        value=int(input("Enter the value for "+col_name+" : "))
        dict_matrix.get(row_name)[col_name]=value
        i=i+1
    row_index=row_index+1
print("out_of_loop")
print(dict_matrix)
```

This will give you a dictionary structured like this :

```
{'row_1': {'a11': 1, 'a12': 2}, 'row_2': {'a21': 3, 'a22': 4}, 'row_3': {'a31': 5, 'a32': 6}, 'row_4': {'a41': 7, 'a42': 8}}
```